# Determine subgroup index

Tags: r, grouping, dplyr

I have a large data frame with groups and subgroups. I would like to determine the index of the subgroup in each group, like shown in the `OUTPUT` column of the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Group = factor(c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B")),
  Subgroup = factor(c("a","a","b","b","b","a","a","b","b")),
  OUTPUT = c(1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2)
)
```

I've tried several possibilities with without any success. I'd like to work with `dplyr`, but I'm not sure how to go about this. The following code returns an unexpected result.

```
require(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(
    OUTPUT_2 = dplyr::id(Subgroup)
  )

#df
#   Group Subgroup OUTPUT_2
#  (fctr)   (fctr)    (int)
#1      A        a        8
#2      A        a        8
#3      A        b        8
#4      A        b        8
#5      A        b        8
#6      B        a        4
#7      B        a        4
#8      B        b        4
#9      B        b        4
```

I've the feeling I'm close, but not getting there. Can anybody help?

Comment: Do you need something like `as.numeric(Subgroup)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `factor` route with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(Group) %>%
    mutate(OUTPUT = as.numeric(factor(Subgroup, levels= unique(Subgroup))))
#   Group Subgroup OUTPUT
#  <fctr>   <fctr>  <dbl>
#1      A        a      1
#2      A        a      1
#3      A        b      2
#4      A        b      2
#5      A        b      2
#6      B        a      1
#7      B        a      1
#8      B        b      2
#9      B        b      2
```

Or another option is `match` with the `unique` elements of 'Subgroup' after grouping by 'Group'

```
df %>%
   group_by(Group) %>% 
   mutate(OUTPUT = match(Subgroup, unique(Subgroup)) )
#   Group Subgroup OUTPUT
#  <fctr>   <fctr>  <int>
#1      A        a      1
#2      A        a      1
#3      A        b      2
#4      A        b      2
#5      A        b      2
#6      B        a      1
#7      B        a      1
#8      B        b      2
#9      B        b      2
```

Comment: very nice, thank you a lot! You get accepted since it's simple and actually involves dplyr like I hoped it would :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution with `data.table` without aggregation:

```
dt[order(Subgroup), Output := cumsum(!duplicated(Subgroup)) , by = .(Group)]
```

This will be much faster compared to methods based on aggregation.

Comment: this won't work if Subgroup elements are shuffled around - e.g. change `dt[6, Subgroup := 'b']` on OP data and try again

Comment: @eddi that is true, but it is easily solvable with 'setkey'

Comment: Bulat, that's true, but even better would be to have `order(Subgroup)` in the `i` argument, which'd not disrupt the original order of `dt` *and* is much efficient since it avoids the reordering (which is expensive).

Comment: @Arun that is very true, thank you for advice. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(df) # or setDT to convert in place

unique(dt[, .(Group, Subgroup)])[, idx := 1:.N, by = Group][dt, on = c('Group', 'Subgroup')]
#   Group Subgroup idx OUTPUT
#1:     A        a   1      1
#2:     A        a   1      1
#3:     A        b   2      2
#4:     A        b   2      2
#5:     A        b   2      2
#6:     B        a   1      1
#7:     B        a   1      1
#8:     B        b   2      2
#9:     B        b   2      2
```

Translation to `dplyr` should be straightforward.

---

Another method, following the idea of using factors from aosmith's comment, is:

```
dt[, idx := as.integer(factor(Subgroup, unique(Subgroup))), by = Group][]
```

This will create a factor with correct levels per Group which *is* the indexing you're after.